# What should i do when HtmlAgilityPack.Document try to Load a link that end with exe?

Tags: c#

This is the function:

```
private static HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument getHtmlDocumentWebClient(string url, bool useProxy, string proxyIp, int proxyPort, string usename, string password)
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            //client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
            client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            client.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
            if (useProxy)
            {
                //Proxy                
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proxyIp))
                {
                    WebProxy p = new WebProxy(proxyIp, proxyPort);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(usename))
                    {
                        if (password == null)
                            password = string.Empty;
                        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(usename, password);
                        p.Credentials = nc;
                    }
                }
            }
            Stream data = client.OpenRead(url);
            doc.Load(data);
            data.Close();
            return doc;
        }
```

Im getting links each itertion in my program and after few times the variable url is:

```
http://appldnld.apple.com/iTunes10/041-7196.20120912.Ber43/iTunesSetup.exe
```

If i mtrying this link in my InternetExplorer it will try to download the file.
But in my program its trying to Load it in the line:

doc.Load(data);

Wich make after some time the program to freeze stuck and in the end when i force to END the application in Task Manager the program throw me an exception:

```
StackOverFlowException was unhandled 

An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in HtmlAgilityPack.dll

System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in HtmlAgilityPack.dll
```

Now i used a breakpoint and the problem happen on the line:

```
doc.Load(data);
```

The question is how should i handle in cases of this links ? Should i ignore them by try and catch or maybe i should consider this as a link ? What if sometime in the future i will want to use this links to download the exe files so maybe try and ctach is not a good idea ?

---

Edited:

This is how the getHtmlDocumentWebClient look like now:

```
private  static HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument getHtmlDocumentWebClient(string url, bool useProxy, string proxyIp, int proxyPort, string usename, string password)
        {

            HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = null;     //Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebRequest class.
            HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = null;   //Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebResponse class
            //Create Request
            myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            myHttpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
            myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/html; encoding='utf-8'";
            //Get Response
            myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

            Stream data = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();//client.OpenRead(url);
            doc.Load(data);
            data.Close();
            return doc;
        }
```

Same problem yet. Whats wrong with the function now and how do i do the actual checking/s for text/html content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the `Content-Type` before trying to parse the response as HTML.
If it isn't `text/html` or one of its variants, don't parse it.

To get the Content-Type, you will need to use `HttpWebRequest` instead of `WebClient`.
You can then check `response.Headers`.

Comment: Just updated now my question. Not sure what to do now and if what i did so far is good. Tried to use HttpWebRequest.